# wc: 'standard input': Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, process, fork, system-calls

I'm emulating bash commands in C language using Exec family of functions.

This is just a partial code of bigger project. Most of the things are hard-coded for now for simplicity, but in future I need to execute any bash command with Pipe or Redirection operator so that's the reason the code is in loop. I know I can use single file descriptor(with out 2d array) to achieve the result for current example but I need to generalise the code for multiple |, > commands. I can't remove the loop.

I'm getting Bad descriptor error even after closing all the descriptors correctly. Unable to find the reason.

```
int main()
{
    int numOfCmds = 2;
    int numOfPipes = numOfCmds -1;
    int pipes[numOfPipes][2];

    for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
        if(pipe(pipes[i])<0) return 1;

    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        int child = fork();
        if(child == 0)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                }
                printf("hey\n");
                dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
                char *cmd1_args[3] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd1_args[0], cmd1_args);
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                }
                printf("bye\n");
                dup2(pipes[i][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                char *cmd2_args[3] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd2_args[0], cmd2_args);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;i<2;j++)
            close(pipes[i][j]);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++) wait(NULL);

    return 0;
```

***Error:***

> hey bye wc: 'standard input': Bad file descriptor 0 wc: -: Bad file
> descriptor Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: I do not see error checks. Not a one. You could add some error checking to your functions, as pipe and friend functions may fail.

Comment: BTW, can you use a debugger?

Comment: I can use but gdb is crashing. I removed error checks as I told it's partial code. I can see hey bye. Issue is with I==1 block which I'm unable to figure out

Comment: "gdb is crashing" - you must have corrupted system. Can you try other debugger?

Comment: @weatherVane yes first dimension is one for now but it can many later. I want to be able to execute multiple bash command with pipes. So I tried only with 2 commands involving single pipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reusing (nested) definitions of `i`.  Use the `-Wshadow` option to GCC to avoid doing that.  And the value of `i` is sometimes beyond the end of the array of pairs of file descriptors, which leads to chaos (undefined behaviour).

You have:

```c
    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        int child = fork();
        if(child == 0)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                }
                printf("hey\n");
                dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
                char *cmd1_args[3] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd1_args[0], cmd1_args);
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                }
                printf("bye\n");
                dup2(pipes[i][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                close(pipes[i][0]);
                char *cmd2_args[3] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd2_args[0], cmd2_args);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Your (outer) loop control variable is `i`; you then have an inner loop controlled by a different `i` that closes some pipes.  And the GCC I use reports that you are accessing `pipes[i][0]` out of bounds in the `dup2()` call for `wc`.

You need to rework your use of `i` (use some different names — `j` and `k` (for 'kids'?) are usable).  And re-review which file pipe descriptors you are closing carefully.

Your parental loop closing file descriptors is:

```c
    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;i<2;j++)
            close(pipes[i][j]);
    }
```

You need to use the `numOfPipes` instead of `numOfCmds`, and you need your inner loop to test `j`, not `i`.

Here's some heavily instrumented code that works.  But the fixes are not very general:

```c
/* SO 7165-1018 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int numOfCmds = 2;
    int numOfPipes = numOfCmds - 1;
    int pipes[numOfPipes][2];

    for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
        if(pipe(pipes[i])<0) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPipes; i++)
        printf("%d: pipe[%d][0] = %d; pipe[%d][1] = %d\n",
               getpid(), i, pipes[i][0], i, pipes[i][1]);

    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        int child = fork();
        printf("%d: child = %d\n", getpid(), child);
        if(child == 0)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    printf("%d: ls: close %d\n", getpid(), pipes[i][0]);
                    close(pipes[i][0]);
                }
                printf("%d: hey\n", getpid());
                dup2(pipes[i][1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                printf("%d: ls: close %d\n", getpid(), pipes[i][1]);
                close(pipes[i][1]);
                char *cmd1_args[3] = {"ls", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd1_args[0], cmd1_args);
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", cmd1_args[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if(i==1)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
                {
                    printf("%d: wc: close %d\n", getpid(), pipes[i][1]);
                    close(pipes[i][1]);
                }
                printf("%d: bye\n", getpid());
                dup2(pipes[0][0], STDIN_FILENO);
                printf("%d: wc: close %d\n", getpid(), pipes[0][0]);
                close(pipes[0][0]);
                char *cmd2_args[3] = {"wc", "-l", NULL};
                execvp(cmd2_args[0], cmd2_args);
                fprintf(stderr, "failed to execute %s\n", cmd2_args[0]);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<numOfPipes;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            printf("parent (%d): close %d\n", getpid(), pipes[i][j]);
            close(pipes[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<numOfCmds;i++)
    {
        int corpse;
        int status;
        if ((corpse = wait(&status)) > 0)
            printf("%d: child %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", getpid(), corpse, status);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One sample run (of program `sh83`, compiled from `sh83.c`) yielded:

```
42654: pipe[0][0] = 3; pipe[0][1] = 4
42654: child = 42655
42655: child = 0
42655: ls: close 3
42654: child = 42656
parent (42654): close 3
parent (42654): close 4
42655: hey
42656: child = 0
42656: wc: close 4
42656: bye
42656: wc: close 3
     128
42654: child 42655 exited with status 0x0000
42654: child 42656 exited with status 0x0000
```

If you're working with multiple processes, I find it is a great help  to prefix most messages with a PID — as shown in the output.

Comment: @Jonathank Leffler Thank you so much I realised my mistakes in the code.